# validate the sequence number in the trailer of a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, numeric-data

We have a  file that arrives daily and has a sequence number in the trailer like

```
9999  TR  SAP _AP Distribution  0000000000000001
```

where `0000000000000001` is the sequence number and the file that comes the next day should have `0000000000000002` and so on.  We need to Validate Sequence Number in input file, reject the file if Sequence Number is duplicate or not matching with expected sequence number.  Need a script that does the validation.

The file name is like `EFEGECC_Timestamp.txt`, e.g. `EFEGECC_20150704.txt` and so on. We have a file coming in everyday of the year.

Comment: What are names of your files to be validated, and how many do you have?  Is that information with a serial number at the last line of file?

Comment: the file name is like EFEGECC_Timestamp.txt ex EFEGECC_20150704.txt and so on. we have a file coming in everyday of the year

Comment: Use `file` for this. Your description almost already looks like a `-m`agic file.

Comment: If a day is missing, should the corresponding sequence number be skipped? E.g. if `EFEGECC_20150101.txt` is present, `EFEGECC_20150102.txt` is missing and `EFEGECC_20150103.txt` is present, should the sequence number in `EFEGECC_20150103.txt` be 2 or 3?

Comment: the sequence number should still be 2 in EFEGECC_20150103.txt

Comment: " duplicate or not matching with expected sequence number" <- isn't that redundant logic? Can the number be a duplicate, yet at the same time match with the expected number?

Comment: If one file comes everyday, can't someone do this task manually? Unless the processing is *completely* automated, someone is going to have to take this received file and run a script. That someone might as well just look at the trailer and check the number against yesterday's file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all files to be validated from the beginning.

```
#!/bin/bash

seqno=1
for i; do
        if tail -1 $i | grep -q $(printf "%016d\$" $seqno); then
                echo "  valid: $i"
                seqno=$((seqno+1))
        else
                echo "invalid: $i"
        fi
done
```

Input:

```
$ grep . EFEGECC*
EFEGECC_20150101.txt:9999  TR  SAP _AP Distribution  0000000000000001
EFEGECC_20150102.txt:9999  TR  SAP _AP Distribution  0000000000000002
EFEGECC_20150103.txt:9999  TR  SAP _AP Distribution  0000000000000002
EFEGECC_20150104.txt:9999  TR  SAP _AP Distribution  0000000000000009
EFEGECC_20150105.txt:9999  TR  SAP _AP Distribution  0000000000000003
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh EFEGECC*
  valid: EFEGECC_20150101.txt
  valid: EFEGECC_20150102.txt
invalid: EFEGECC_20150103.txt
invalid: EFEGECC_20150104.txt
  valid: EFEGECC_20150105.txt
```